# Order varchar string as numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, types, casting

Is it possible to order result rows by a `varchar` column cast to `integer` in Postgres 8.3?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It's absolutely possible.

```
ORDER BY varchar_col::int
```

Be sure to have valid integer literals in your `varchar` column for each entry or you get an exception `invalid input syntax for integer`. Leading and trailing white space is ok - that's trimmed automatically.

If that's the case, though, then why not convert the column to `integer` to begin with? Smaller, faster, cleaner, simpler.

#### How to avoid exceptions?

##### Postgres 16 or newer

**If** the input might not be valid integer literals, use the dedicated function [`pg_input_is_valid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-VALIDITY) to test without raising an exception:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN pg_input_is_valid(varchar_col, 'integer') THEN varchar_col::int END
```

SQL `CASE` defaults to `null` in the absence of `ELSE` - which sorts last in default ascending order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

The new built-in function is faster and more reliable than below manual solution. Also different in that it does not try to fix broken input.

##### Postgres 15 or older

To remove non-digit characters before the cast and thereby avoid possible exceptions:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(regexp_replace(varchar_col, '\D', '', 'g'), '')::int
```

- The [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) expression effectively removes all non-digits, so only digits remain or an empty string. (See below.)
- `\D` is shorthand for the character class `[^[:digit:]]`, meaning all non-digits (`[^0-9]`).
  In old Postgres versions with the outdated setting `standard_conforming_strings = off`, you have to use Posix escape string syntax `E'\\D'` to escape the backslash `\`. This was default in Postgres 8.3, so you'll need that for your outdated version.
- The 4th parameter `g` is for *"globally"*, instructing to replace *all* occurrences, not just the first.
- You *may* want to allow a leading dash (`-`) for negative numbers.
- If the the string has no digits at all, the result is an empty string which is not valid for a cast to `integer`. Convert empty strings to `NULL` with [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF). (You might consider `0` instead.)

The result is guaranteed to be valid. This procedure is for a cast to **`integer`** as requested in the body of the question, *not for `numeric`* as the title mentions.

#### How to make it fast?

One way is an [index on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html).

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_varchar_col2int_idx ON tbl
(cast(NULLIF(regexp_replace(varchar_col, '\D', '', 'g'), '') AS integer));
```

Then use the same expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
cast(NULLIF(regexp_replace(varchar_col, '\D', '', 'g'), '') AS integer)
```

Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` whether the functional index actually gets used.

Comment: Any way to avoid that exception? :)

Comment: @Jauzsika: you will have to define first what the result should be for non-integer values. Sort last? Or delete any non-digit characters before the cast?

Comment: Thanks for the exception part. That regexp looks slow, am I right?

Comment: @Jauzsika: Definitely slower than the plain cast, but not that much. The fact that you have to compute the values at all is the major slow-down here. If you want fast, either convert the column in the table to integer, or add a redundant column that holds the pre-computed integer. Then you can index the column, which will make it *a lot* faster (provided the query is simple and the index can be used for the sort). **Or** use an index on an expression. I amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the exhausting training :)).

Comment: EPIC COMMENT +1 !!
Just one append : E'\\D' not worked for me, produced this error > "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "ee" does not exist", then I put just '\D' and worked like a charm.
I'm using postgresql9.3 version . thanks again!

Comment: Wow! +1 for an awesome answer. The index is amazing. I had no idea you could do such magic.

Answer (score 9):

Also in case you want to order by a text column that has something convertible to float, then this does it:

```
select * 
from your_table
order by cast(your_text_column as double precision) desc;
```