# WARNING: nonstandard use of escape in a string literal

Tags: regex, postgresql, escaping

I have query to remove double space and convert it to single space.

```
UPDATE tablename SET name=trim(regexp_replace(name,'\s\s+',' ', 'g'));
```

It gives error:

> ```
> WARNING: nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
> HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
> ```

Comment: This is probably an old version of PostgreSQL, can you tell us which one?

Comment: version 1.22.0 beta

Comment: That's your version of pgAdmin most likely. What's your version of Postgres? `SELECT version();`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter
PostgreSQL 9.0.18 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running an old version of Postgres with the setting `escape_string_warning = on` (default) and `standard_conforming_strings = off` (**outdated!**, default is `on` since Postgres 9.1). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-ESCAPE-STRING-WARNING)

> `escape_string_warning`(`boolean`)
>
> When on, a warning is issued if a backslash (`\`) appears in an ordinary
>   string literal (`'...'` syntax) and `standard_conforming_strings` is `off`.
>   The default is `on`. (...)

To just fix the syntax and get rid of the `WARNING`:

```
trim(regexp_replace(name, E'\\s\\s+', ' ', 'g'))
```

**Proper solution:** Upgrade to a current version of Postgres, or fix the outdated setting to `standard_conforming_strings =`**`on`**.
In modern Postgres, the expression you have is valid as is.

To be precise, [`\s` is the class shorthand for `[[:space:]]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE), which includes *any* kind of [white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (incl. tab, nbsp etc.). Your expression replaces any string of two or more white space char with a single space char. The expression to fit your description would be:

```
trim(regexp_replace(name,'  +', ' ', 'g'))
```

... which works regardless of version and above settings.

Related:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- [Order varchar string as numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502505/order-varchar-string-as-numeric/8502570#8502570)

Comment: If using PHP you can use pg_escape_literal (NOT pg_escape_string)  which will delimit and escape your strings correctly according to your postgres settings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php

Answer (score 0):

The below should also work.

```
trim(regexp_replace(name,E'\s+','\s{2}',
```

Comment: Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.