# Rails PostgreSQL sort by integer value of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I made a strategic mistake when developing database architecture on my Rails app

Now I have to implement sorting by price feature using

```
MyModel.order('price DESC')
```

**price is a string** type in the database, which cause 50 to be greater than 2000 for example

Are there any ways to implement such `.order()` without changing database structure?

**EDIT:**

I switched to correct type (integer) for price column. It took me an hour only to refactor.

Comment: which rdbms are u using?

Comment: Im using PostgreSQL

Comment: I think it is better to migrate column type from string to float if possible. Otherwise you should cast column: `ORDER BY price::float`.

Comment: Yea  Oleksandr Avoyants is right you really should just migrate the database table to have the right value. You are going to really hinder yourself if you just keep finding work arounds.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With PostgreSQL you will want to cast your string to `integer`/`float`/`decimal` (after you decide you 100% will not go and change the column type to *correct* one):

```
MyModel.order('price::integer DESC')
```

Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502570/3102718) to make it work fast.